# What exactly does a BAD signature mean?

Tags: gnupg, signature

About 16 hours ago I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04.5 image from [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/bionic/) alongside its checksum file and GnuPG signature. Verifying the checksum file using the signature results in a BAD signature warning. Why is that happening and should I be worried?

What exactly does a BAD signature mean? What is the next logical step?

```
gpg: Signature made Thu 13 Aug 2020 08:02:20 PM +05 
gpg:              using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092 
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012)
<cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. It has nothing to with Notepad shenanigans. Both the checksum and the signature files were downloaded and saved correctly. 

Firefox recognized the .gpg file extension, while the checksum file was saved by opening it > right-click > Save Page As...

Comment: Did you follow the exact steps mentioned in [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) website?

Comment: @technastic_tc Yes, I did.

Comment: Try downloading the checksum file by right click-->save link as and retry.

Comment: Same message. BAD signature.

Comment: Add the output of `gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The signature is bad, you can't do anything about it. It is Canonical's problem and it looks like they don't care. There was a post on reddit about it, but no reaction.

In the meantime the signature is good [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.5/release/) but it only contains server ISOs.

Never use signed software with a bad signature, it could have been tampered with.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then I'd consider it critical. How do we contact Canonical developers and maintainers directly and inform them about it?

Comment: I downloaded both the files and I verified it. The output was a good signature. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2x25WWspTs/ BTW, tagging users in an answer won't notify the user.

Comment: @technastic_tc You're doing it again. Please stop. It is evident they've reuploaded the sig recently. Go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ and checkout modify time on SHA256SUMS.gpg

Comment: @Akbarkhon Variskhanov They've reuploaded the sig. It is OK now. Other files wasn't changed so you're iso should be OK, it was just the sig file broken. Be sure to verify it with sha256sum btw in case you downloaded it not via torrent.

Comment: Please add the link of the Reddit post in the answer. It'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what is more important is to know why one can usually get this verification result. The message like :`gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012)`

one usually can get in case if the signing secret key was missing at the time the dvd dist "Release" file like in : `dvd-image/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Release` was gpg signed.

Possibly a misstyped parameter with the path to the dvd-signing secret key, given on a commandline to a script thet was upgrading the dvd-image pool and then resigning the release files.

Note: Provided information is based on my research and personal experiance creating my own d-i based installer based dvd for ubuntu - jammy.